# ¿Cómo decrementar un numero al usar setOnLongClickListener?

Tags: java, android-studio, botón

Tengo una enorme duda con la implementación de setOnLongClickListener;
Lo que pretendo hacer es, cada vez que se presione un botón un número vaya en decremento mientras siga pulsando el botón:

```
btn_less.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            int valor = Integer.parseInt(etx_cantidad.getText().toString());
            int less = valor - 1;
            if (less <= 0) {
                Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "Has llegado al valor minimo.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                bar.setActionTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorRojoVivo));
                bar.show();
                aut_total.setText(String.valueOf(precio));
            } else {
                etx_cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(less));
                float price = (float) precio;
                float total = less * price;
                BigDecimal bd= new BigDecimal(total);
                bd= bd.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                aut_total.setText(bd.toString());
                monto = total;
                if (total < 100000) {
                    aut_total.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.PrimaryText));
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Este es la implementación pero solo decrementa una vez, yo lo que quiero es  que entre más se mantenga presionado vaya decrementando

Comment: Quizá seria mejor hacerlo mediante `onTouchListener()` contando el tiempo transcurrido, [revisa esta pregunta y la respuesta dada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7934245/5587982)

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo, me funciono con ese metodo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta declarar `valor` fuera de `onLongClick(View view)`

```js
btn_valor.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        int valor;
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            valor = Integer.parseInt(etx_cantidad.getText().toString());
            valor--;
            if (valor <= 0) {
                Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "Has llegado al valor minimo.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                bar.setActionTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorRojoVivo));
                bar.show();
                aut_total.setText(String.valueOf(precio));
            } else {
                etx_cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(valor));
                float price = (float) precio;
                float total = valor valor * price;
                BigDecimal bd= new BigDecimal(total);
                bd= bd.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                aut_total.setText(bd.toString());
                monto = total;
                if (total < 100000) {
                    aut_total.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.PrimaryText));
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Lo acabo de implementar pero no hay cambio alguno se queda en un valor absoluto, pero por lo que veo el método que necesito es el settOnTouchListener.